# Verify business rules

Tags: java, design-patterns, jsf-2.2, business-rules

I have some rules to validade my model class MyBean. Now it's done by ifs chain inside only one method (validateMyBean). I don't like this way, it seems fuzzy.

**What's the best approach for validade many business rules?**

```
public class MyBean {
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private int age;
    private String country;
    private double otherField;
    //getter and setter
}

public class MyBeanFacade {
    //database connection and other methods
}

public class MyBeanBusiness {
    private MyBeanFacade facade;
    private MyBean myBean;

    public boolean validateMyBean() {

        if(!this.myBean.getEmail().contains("@") {
             return false;
        }

        if(this.myBean.getAge()<18 || this.myBean.getAge()>150) {
             return false;
        }

        if(this.myBean.getCountry().startsWith("A") || this.myBean.getCountry().startsWith("B") || this.myBean.getCountry().startsWith("C") || ) {
             return false;
        }

        if(this.myBean.getOtherField() >= 0.123) {
             return false;
        }

        if(facade.existsEmail(myBean.getEmail())) {
             return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the Validation API?

Comment: Some links @chrylis ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html for starters

Comment: A rule based system, e.g. Drools.

Answer (score 1):

Put the validation logic into the setter methods, to prevent invalid values from ever being set. Throw an exception to reject a given value. This eliminates the need for a validation method, and guarantees the validation code will run for every set value.

Better yet, eliminate the setters by taking the values in a constructor, to guarantee that all validation is executed. If there are too many parameters for one constructor, make use of the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the business rules standalone classes following the [Specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). This way you can unit test each rule.

For the rules that return `boolean` value it is natural to implement Java's [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) interface. The `Predicate` rules can then be combined with logical operators `and` and `or`. They also make a natural fit into Java 8's functional programming model.

For an example of the Specification pattern see [here](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns).